# Solution to start/stop many instances of one application

Tags: configuration, shell-scripting

I have one tool that performs a long-running task. This tool accepts a configuration file. Right now I need to run simultaneously about 15 instances with different configs (using screen for this).

All instances should be restarted at the same time (or almost the same time).

But I think this task can be automated somehow to start/stop all possible configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it can, that's what shellscripts are for. Lets assume your configs are all in `/etc/myapp`. Then something like this will do the trick:

```
killall myapp
while pgrep myapp &>/dev/null; do
  sleep 0.1
done
for config in /etc/myapp/*; do
    screen -S mapp.$config /usr/local/bin/myapp --config $config
done
```

As this is only tangentially related to server administration, I think it's better to ask any followup questions on the [unix&linux site](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: And this does stop his processes how? :-)

Comment: The killall will do that ;) (added after you comment, thanks)

Comment: any thoughts on `killall` versus `pkill`?

Comment: what about place all application under same screen session inside different windows ?